# TypeError: this.state.modifedGrowth.toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am working with react and I have input box having initial value but user can change that value. from backend I am value like 0.01999 so I use Math.round but that is allowing me to add decimal value and if I am using toFixed it gives me error
`TypeError: this.state.modifedGrowth.toFixed is not a function` can please anyone tell me how to do that?
here is my code

```
 <input
                type="text"
             //   value={Math.round(this.state.modifedGrowth * 100) / 100}
                 value={this.state.modifedGrowth.toFixed(2).toString()}
                onChange={e => this.updateGrowthValue(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={e => this.props.updateModifiedGrowth(e.target.value)}
              />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the limited source there, it looks like `this.state.modifedGrowth` is a string. Strings don't have a `.toFixed()` method - if it's numerical data you're expecting convert it to a number first - `Number(this.state.modifedGrowth)`

Comment: `updateGrowthValue(key) {this.setState({ modifedGrowth: key });}`

Answer (score 0):

I know this not the right solution but we can say it's fix I change it into string and manipulated that

```
componentDidMount() {
    let modifedProgramGrowth = '';
    if (this.props.modifedProgramGrowth .toString().includes('.')) {
      let GrowthArr= this.props.modifedGrowth 
        .toString()
        .split('.');
      modifedProgramGrowth =
        GrowthArr[0] + '.' + GrowthArr[1].substr(0, 2);
    } else {
      modifedGrowth = this.props.modifedGrowth ;
    }
    this.setState({ modifedProgramGrowth });
  }
```